# Unable to manually install ssl certfile to .app domain hosted in docker container

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, haproxy

I am trying to set ssl termination for redthis.app domain in haproxy 2.4.2 but getting the following error from haproxy container

```
[ALERT]    (1) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:4] : 'bind *:443' :
  unable to load private key from file '/etc/haproxy/ssl/gdredthis.app.pem.key'.
   '/etc/haproxy/ssl/gdredthis.app.pem.key' is present but cannot be read or parsed'.
```

Below is the sequence I tried,

1. Setup Haproxy with following config

```
frontend haproxyserver-http
    mode http
    bind *:80
#   bind *:443
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/gdredthis.app.pem
#   http-request redirect scheme https code 301 unless { ssl_fc }
    timeout client 5s
    default_backend golangwebserver
```

2. Exposed ports in docker-compose file

```
services:
  haproxy:
    image: vivekanandaraman/red-business-app:haproxy-2.4.2
    container_name: haproxy
    user: root
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-haproxy
    ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
    volumes:           
       - type: bind
         source: /opt/red/haproxy/etc/
         target: /usr/local/etc/haproxy/
       - type: bind
         source: /opt/dvolume/etc/haproxy/ssl/redthis.app/
         target: /etc/haproxy/ssl/         
    networks: 
            - my-shared-network
```

3. Concatenated .crt, gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt in gdredthis.app.pem and stored private key in gdredthis.app.pem.key as mentioned in https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/221#issuecomment-687297668.
4. I gave 777 privilege to the key file in
   `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1707 Jul 26 17:40 gdredthis.app.pem.key`
5. To me it looks like the haproxy user which executes the service in docker is unable to read the  gdredthis.app.pem.key file
6. I have tried certificates from Let'sencrypt and godaddy but getting the same error. I am able to access the website through port 80 but with the dangerous warning in the browser.

I am totally stuck any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you do all those things? What do you mean by 'manually'? Where did you put the pem and how did you give access to it to your container? How did you run your container? Have you tested the validity of the pem file?

Comment: I pasted my haproxy service above. I ran this container as root. Placed pem in docker host /opt/dvolume/etc/haproxy/ssl/redthis.app/. In the image I pulled from docker hub https://github.com/docker-library/haproxy/blob/973f43b2d1c5c0d57274002e216761c0baedf6c0/2.4/Dockerfile, I can see that haproxy is created to execute the image. I haven't tested the validity of .pem file. How to do it.